# Extract last 100 files in all subdirectories, each directory has variable number of files

Tags: command-line, directory

I have a directory with 6 subdirectories. Each subdirectory also have a variable number of subdirectories. These last directories have variable numbers of `*.jpg` files. The jpg files are named in the form `0000.jpg`, `0001.jpg` and so on.

I am interested in getting the last 100 `*.jpg` files ( all directories have > 100 files), and storing them in separate directories with similar structure as the original directories.

What is the best way of doing it?

Comment: I was almost going to ask if you tried anything at all?

Comment: This is not Ubuntu-related question, try http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @madneon this question is absolutely on topic here

Comment: Do you mean the last 100 files for each subdirectory, or the last 100 in the whole tree? And if the latter, how do you define which ones are the "last"?

Answer (score 0):

In the parent with the 6 subdirectories:

```
mkdir ../newdirs
```

Then:

```
for d in */*; do mkdir -p ../newdirs/"$d"; i=0; j=$(stat "$d"/* --printf "%i\n" | wc -l); for f in "$d"/*; do [[ -f "$f" ]] && (( (j - ++i) < 100 )) && echo mv -v -- "$f" ../newdirs/"$d"; done; done
```

Remove `echo` after testing to actually move the files.
More readably:

```
for d in */*; do 
  mkdir -p ../newdirs/"$d" 
  i=0
  j=$(stat "$d"/* --printf "%i\n" | wc -l)
  for f in "$d"/*; do 
    [[ -f "$f" ]] && 
    (( (j - ++i) < 100 )) && 
      echo mv -v -- "$f" ../newdirs/"$d"
  done
done
```

#### Notes

- `mkdir ../newdirs` make a new directory for the moved files at the same level as the current one (ie in the parent `..` of both)
- `for d in */*; do` for each sub-sub directory...
- `mkdir -p ../newdirs/"$d"` make a directory in the parallel structure, using `-p` to create parent directories as needed and
- `i=0` set a variable to 0 for counting iterations
- `j=$(stat "$d"/* --printf "%i\n" | wc -l)` count the files in the sub-subdirectory and assign this number to `j`
- `for f in "$d"/*; do` for all the contents of the sub-subdirectories
- `[[ -f "$f" ]] &&` if it's a file
- `(( (j - ++i) < 100 )) &&` and if the number of files in the directory minus the number of times the loop has been run is less than 100, then...
- `mv -v -- "$f" ../newdirs/"$d"` move the file to the corresponding directory in the new structure.

`for` iterates over files in an ordered way, so this method will give the last 100 files as listed numerically.

You can adjust `../newdirs` to the path you want.